# Bash string split by delimiter constrained by number of characters

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I want to split a long text separated by spaces through bash, but I fail. The command below splits into characters, but not delimiters.

```
echo "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog" | fold -w 10
echo "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog" | sed -e 's/.\{9\}/&\n/g'
```

It would be nice to have it for some user bash interaction.

Input syntax

```
format_text 10 "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog"
```

Output:

```
The quick 
fox jumped 
over the 
lazy dog
```

You must notice that the third line would cut "l" letter from "lazy" off if not for spacing spacing rule.

Update:
The current result is good, There is some issue with the work slicer I cannot get by myself: it does not break words before the limit is transpassed.

```
#!/bin/bash

printHeader () {
    declare -i line_length=$3
    
    # Upper and lower fences 
    local upper_command="print \"$1\" *" 
    local upper_fence="$(python -c "$upper_command $line_length")"
    
    local lower_command="print \"$2\" *"
    local lower_fence="$(python -c "$lower_command $line_length")"
    
    # Slice words by some chracter counter
    local regex_counter="s/(.{$line_length}) /\1\n/g"
    
    # Complete line with dots and a pipe
    local res="$line_length - length"
    local repeat_pattern='$(repeat res \".\"; echo)'
    local fill_command="{res=($res); printf \"%s%s|\n\", $0, $repeat_pattern}"

    echo "$upper_fence"

    sed -r "$regex_counter" <<< $4

    echo "$lower_fence"
}

printHeader "#" "#" 10 "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog"
```

Current output without final token:

```
##########
The quick fox
jumped over
the lazy dog
##########
```

Comment: I added the examples as you suggested

Comment: Great question! It is an open question for the problem. We may tag the line with a <<-- at the end, or something like that. Or maybe break the word relentlessly.

Comment: But lets take the case where the number of characters is greater than the greatest word. It seems reasonable for a natural language text,

Comment: `| fmt -w 11` .. (think you have to count the newline too)

Comment: Sublime answer. It is already ok for me! In case I want to put some delimiter to denote the line limit, does the code changes much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
sed -r 's/([^ .]+ [^ .]+) /\1\n/g' <<< "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog"
```

```
The quick
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
```

The character set `[^ .]+` means one or more `+` characters of any kind `.` excluding the `^`  whitespaces. So the capture group `([^ .]+ [^ .]+)` matches for patterns as `string string`. The whole regular expression has an additional whitespace at the end `([^ .]+ [^ .]+)`  (it could be included in the capture group in order to preserve it).

With `sed` by using the substitute `s` command we replace the matched pattern by the content of the first capture group `\1` and a new line character `\n` instead of the whitespace. By the flag `g` we repeat the command to the end of each line. The `-r` option activates the extended regular expressions.

---

Update - this is the actual answer:

```bsh
sed -r 's/(.{8}) /\1\n/g' <<< "How do we know it is going to match the pre-defined number of characters?"
```

```
How do we
know it is
going to
match the
pre-defined
number of
characters?
```

In this example we capture strings with length at least 8 characters (including whitespaces) followed by a whitespace.
We can check the actual length of the output lines in a way as this:

```bsh
sed -r 's/(.{8}) /\1\n/g' <<< "How do we know it is going to match the pre-defined number of characters?" \
    | awk '{print length}'
```

```
9
10
8
9
11
9
11
```

And by the help of the answers of the question [How to use printf to print a character multiple times? [awk]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37295695/6543935) we can achieve the desired result.

```bsh
sed -r 's/(.{8}) /\1\n/g' <<< "How do we know it is going to match the pre-defined number of characters?" \
    | awk '{rest=(12 - length); printf "%s%s|\n", $0, substr(".........", 1, rest)}'
```

```
How do we...|
know it is..|
going to....|
match the...|
pre-defined.|
number of...|
characters?.|
```

---

In case you want to break the words remove the final whitespace from the above regular expression `/(.{8})/`. Here is an example where the max line length will be exactly 10 characters or less, where the second `sed` command will trim the whitespaces around each new line.

```bsh
sed -r 's/(.{10})/\1\n/g' <<< "How do we know it is going to match the pre-defined number of characters?" \
    | sed -r 's/(^ | $)//g' \
    | awk '{rest=(10 - length); printf "%s%s|\n", $0, substr(".........", 1, rest)}'
```

```
How do we.|
know it is|
going to..|
match the.|
pre-define|
d number o|
f characte|
rs?.......|
```

Comment: How do we know it is going to match the pre-defined number of characters?

Comment: Hi, @BrunoHenriquePeixoto. I've updated the answer with little joke of your question.

Comment: GREAT! The last last wish, genius. May you put a cherry on the top by delimiting the last character (either {max_val} or {max_val+1}). May be some symbol | or #, does not matter.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto, I didn't understand this requirement. Probably you need a second expression as: `sed -r -e 's/(.{8}) /\1\n/g' -e 's/(.)$/\|\1/'` but I'm not sure. Or if you want to modify each new line the laziest way is by a second processing as: `sed -r 's/(.{8}) /\1\n/g' in-file.txt | sed -r 's/(.)$/\|\1/'`

Comment: Example: Given your profile name "pa4080" (6 digits), the maximum number of 10 line digits and delimiter pipe '|', and dots for trailing space, the output must be "pa4080....|", without the double quotes.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto, please check the update :)

Comment: You should be on stack oveflow hall of fame

Comment: The substr snippet seems a little sloppy. Some repeat routine suits better. We did a great job!

Comment: There is an issue with the sed we implemented. Take a look at the main body of the post.

Comment: Hi, @BrunoHenriquePeixoto, if you want to break the word try to remove the final whitespace from the regex: `/(.{8}) /` => `/(.{8})/`. I've added an update to the answer.

Comment: I want to give more cotes to the answer! :(! THANKS

Comment: votes, hugs, money, calories, credit, stars, whatever counts

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto, you can just upvote it by clicking at the arrow up :)

Comment: I will upvote every day of my life.

Comment: Your reward: https://github.com/brunolnetto/engage